# Ubuntu phone release in India

Tags: phone

I'm a devoted Ubuntu user and I haven't bought a smartphone yet. Its merely because I dont like either of Android or Microsoft OS on phones. I'm waiting for the launch of Ubuntu-powered phones & tablets in India. Have these been launched in other countries ? If yes, then please provide the details of them as I'm curious to know.

I use a Nokia Asha 501 phone and will be using it until a better phone than the so-called "smartphones" would be released and would lke Ubuntu to be the fiirst one to make a debut after that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release dates of hardware are really not the focus of AskUbuntu and if you want an Ubuntu phone keep an eye out for news on it from tech news sites or Ubuntu related news sites, and/or Ubuntu on twitter, facedbook and google+.

On http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register you can register to get the latest news if you want to receive it through mail.

The [insight](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/02/06/bqs-new-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition-the-smartphone-that-puts-content-and-services-at-your-fingertips/) sites has some info on the phone and also lists the places that are going to get updated the first when there is news.

The Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition is about to get [released](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/the-first-ubuntu-phone-is-going-on-sale.html) in Europa (and then specificly Spain) but this is a flash sales, so a limited amount and a limited time. Besides a release in China and Europe by Meizu next there is nothing new.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance and informaton. I didnt knew how to know if there's a ubuntu release in India, that's why asked in AskUbuntu. :)